# Flutter - text and icons not displaying sometimes

Tags: flutter

Sometimes after turning on my app, user see not rendered screen.
Buttons are available, but no labels and icons are printed.

I didn't notice it with debug version, only release.

In some cases restarting app helps, and sometimes user has to install the app again.

What may be causing this issue?

Broken screen:

[image: bad]

And this is how it should look like

[image: good]

Code seems to be rather standard, e.g. logo, 'Slift' string is created this way:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BorderedText(
        strokeWidth: strokeWidth,
        strokeColor: ThemeColors.getColor3(),
        child: Text(
          'SLift',
          style: GoogleFonts.baloo(
            textStyle:
                TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.none, fontSize: fontSize),
          ),
        ));
  }
```

Comment: Suggest you show us your code.

Comment: @GrahamD ok, added logo build method

Comment: The problem is not the logo, it probably is a flex widget (Column, Row, ListView). Try opening the devtools to inspect the widget tree and properties of the elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you using `MediaQuery` in your code? Because sometimes it works differently on release and debug mode.

Comment: Yes, I'm using MediaQuery to adjust widgets size to user's screen

Comment: This was the issue, MediaQuery sometimes was giving 0 as height or width at app startup, and it was causing that my widgets were broken. Carrying 0 scenario helped me, thank you very much! 
More you can read in this thread: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25827